# How can I make the vertices of a tree graph clickable?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, interactive, trees, user-interface

Would it be possible to make the vertices of a tree graph clickable, executing a function when clicked?

Specifically, I am using Mathematica / the Wolfram Language to prototype a modern, microtonal synthesizer I call 'PTOLEMUSE'.  Its function is to afford a person the ability to hear the sound of epimoric / superparticular ratios in relation to a tonic frequency in hertz.  Here's what I have so far:

```
limitation = 32 ;
relations = List[];
reciprocals = List[];

EpimoricRatios = # / (# - 1) & [ Range[2, limitation] ] ;
ReciprocalRatios = (# - 1) / # & [ Range[2, limitation] ];

For[child = 1, 2 child < Length[EpimoricRatios], child++,
  AppendTo[relations, {EpimoricRatios[[child]] \[UndirectedEdge]
     EpimoricRatios[[2 child]],
    EpimoricRatios[[child]] \[UndirectedEdge]
     EpimoricRatios[[2 child + 1]]}]];


For[child = 1, 2 child < Length[ReciprocalRatios], child++,
  AppendTo[reciprocals, {ReciprocalRatios[[child]] \[UndirectedEdge]
     ReciprocalRatios[[2 child]],
    ReciprocalRatios[[child]] \[UndirectedEdge]
     ReciprocalRatios[[2 child + 1]]}]];

GraphTree[TreeGraph[Flatten[relations], VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
GraphTree[TreeGraph[Flatten[reciprocals], VertexLabels -> "Name"],
 TreeLayout -> Bottom]
```

This produces the following tree graphs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can apply Button to the nodes. You can do this either when constructing the nodes/edges, or you can use TreeMap on the GraphTrees that you create later.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe something like this:

```
upperGraph = 
  TreeGraph[Map[Button[#, Speak[#]] &, Flatten[relations], {-1}], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
upperTree = GraphTree[upperGraph, ImageSize -> 1000, TreeLayout -> Top]
```

(Speak is just an example, you'd use whatever your special function is)

Comment: My friend, you *TOTALLY ROCK!*  this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: I apparently don't have enough credits to boost the score of your answer, unfortunately.  Yet I tried the code, and am very pleased!  THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: You're welcome. I should say that what I did was a quick-and-dirty example. You should experiment a bit to come up with something clean and maintainable.